# Enable Basic Http Authentication asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication

Im trying to enable Basic Http Authentication for my asp.net mvc application. While I can find loads of examples how actual handle the Authorization header I cant find out how to enable the browser to ask for these.

Is it not possible to set a setting like this in the web.config of the Application?

Answer (score 0):

To make the browser ask for the basic authentication credentials, your server has to return a 401 http response with the correct header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="basic"
```

In ASP.Net MVC 5 this can be acomplished by creating an OWIN authentication handler and registering it in the OWIN pipeline.